# How can I send URL variable to zend index controllers index action

Tags: router, zend-framework

```
http://example.com/index/index/color/red/id/230
```

For the above URL zend framework breaks it like the following -

```
module : default
controller : index
action : index
color : red
id : 230
```

But I want to skip the `/index/index` (/controller/action) part. What should I do to achieve the same result with the following URL -

```
http://example.com/color/red/id/230
```

Do I need to write a router for this? Please help me to build one. I tried the following in my routers.ini but it is now working -

```
routes.index.route = /
routes.index.defaults.module = default
routes.index.defaults.controller = index
routes.index.defaults.action = index
```

Please someone help me with this problem. Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need a route and you'll need to tell zend whats the route like. for example:

```
routes.index.route = "/color/:color/id/:id"
```

will give you something like: http://example.com/color/red/id/123

or even a bit shorter:

```
routes.index.route = "/color/:color/:id"
```

would give you http://example.com/color/red/123

your route above just points to the www root. thats why it's not working. btw. did you read this one? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: Yes I visited that link and it helped me a lot. I was looking for some generic solution compared to this router which is very specific with the arguments (i.e. color & id). But if I have a lot more range of arguments, then I need to write all combinations of possible routing rules. I wonder, might there be any more generic solution?

Comment: AFAICR you should be able to use a wildcard at the end, like: /color/:color/* and then pass optional key/value pairs as much you like. (should work ;))